# Showing tick in checkbox before disappearing

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I have this code below: when you tick the `checkbox`, a `spinner`, `button` and the `checkbox` disappear.

But when I run the app and tick the `checkbox`, the `checkbox` sort of just disappears without showing the 'tick' in the box? Is there a way to make it so I can see the box with the tick, then the elements sort of *fade* out?

Thanks!

Code:

```
newCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // makes the set disappear when checkbox is ticked.
        newCheckbox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        newButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```

Comment: put your code in a handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
newCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // makes the set disappear when checkbox is ticked.

            newCheckBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            newButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            newCheckBox.animate().alpha(0.0f).setDuration(1000).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                    newCheckBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });

            newButton.animate().alpha(0.0f).setDuration(1000).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                    newButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });

            spinner.animate().alpha(0.0f).setDuration(1000).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set checkbox is checked(ticked) or not manually before disappearing checkbox.

```
newCheckbox.setChecked(isChecked); //isChecked = Checkbox clicked && !isChecked = checkbox not clicked
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try using a [TimerTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask) and handler for this. Which will change the Checkbox's `VISIBILITY` after a delay you mention.

Example code:

```
newCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)     {
        // makes the set disappear when checkbox is ticked.

        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {          
            @Override
            public void run() {
            // this code will be executed after 2 seconds 
            newCheckbox.setVisibility(View.GONE);      
            newButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }, 2000);

    }
});
```

So your Views will fade out after 2 seconds. You can set the milliseconds as per your requirement.